# Write a function that crosses out up to n-1 signs of a n-letter word, and returns the amount of unique strings created that way

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Let's say we have the string* abcd, which I will refer to as "word". The program should return the amount of unique strings* that are made by crossing out zero or more letters from "abcd". In this particular example, these unique strings* are "abcd", "abc", "abd", "acd", "bcd", "ab", "ac", "ad", "bc", "bd", "cd", "a", "b", "c", "d". Therefore, in this case, the program should return `15`. Using `vector`s and `string`s in this assignment is forbidden, so I will have to use `char[]` arrays instead. The use of the word string* above is to avoid complicating the already complicated task. By string I mean `char[]`.
So far my idea is to create arrays that store the strings with the same length. The number of such strings I find using the binomial formula. (For example the number of 3-letter strings from a 4-letter word is C(3,4). So in a for-loop I create the required arrays to accomodate the strings and add only those strings that aren't already in that array. Then I return the number of elements in the array.

```cpp
//size is the size of the word, i is the number of crossed out letters
int total=0; //stores number of all possible little strings
for(int i=1; i<size; i++){
        int sizeOfSubstring=binomial(size-i, size);
        char substrings[sizeOfSubstring][size-i];
        //populate the substrings array and return the number of char[] arrays added to it. 
        //Then add that number to total.
    }
```

However, as you can clearly see, this problem is already complicated. I bypass the C++ requirement for constant array sizes by using GCC. But it gets even worse, when you have to populate the array of strings. For example, we need to add "abc", "abd", "acd", "bcd" to `substrings[4][3]`. And then the same procedure for substrings[6][2] etc. This will require a function like

```cpp
void addSubstring(char crossedOutIndexes[], char word[], char substr[][]){
    //I haven't implemented that yet
}
```

I am asking this question because I already have great difficulties with this problem and I don't know how to implement the `addSubstring()` function. Is this even the right idea to solve the problem?

Comment: So in your C++ class the right thing to do is use invalid C++ code (variable length arrays) instead of valid C++ code (strings and vectors). I know that isn't your fault, but I would be knocking on the course directors door asking them what they think they are doing.

Comment: Do you actually need to generate the substrings or just figure out how many are possible?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I need to know only how many they are. But how am I going to count them without generating them?

Comment: The best way to solve this problem would be to invest the time to write your own simple string and vector classes. I'm completely sure of this. You could use them for the rest of the course as well. They would definitely be useful.

Comment: @john I know. It''s psychedelic

Comment: I have an idea. Repeated strings causing different numbers from the sum of all combinations occur in cases such as baab, where we have two identical characters next to each other. If I remove one of the 'a's, I won't get two repeated strings ''bab''

Comment: What is more, the problems actually occur when I have a palyndrome

Answer (score 0):

I recommend first solving the problem without the complicated cases. For instance, assume your input will never have repeated letters. Then solve it manually on paper for a string of 2 characters, then 3, then 4, until you see a pattern develop as to an algorithm you manually use when doing it by hand. Then code that, and get it working.  Once that's working. Solve the next problem, duplicates. Well there's a couple options there. Don't add a word if it's already in your list or remove all duplicates from the list.

As to variable length arrays, your initial solution of using a compiler that supports variable length arrays is fine for the first version. Another possibility is simply over allocating an array of strings. For instance an array of 10000 filled with empty strings. While memory inefficient, it's fine for learning. Once you have a working solution you can always move to a standard container like `std::vector`.

One thing that happens here is that learners often get great advice. But they're still learning so the advice just overwhelms them. There's nothing wrong with using a compiler that supports variable length arrays, it just locks you in to that tool.

I do recommend finding a development environment with a great debugger. One that will let you step through the code line by line and see what's happening. Visual Studio Community is the free one, that I'm familiar with. But I know there are others. I just don't know what they are.

Comment: I started with Visual Studio (I had been working there with C# so it was a natural choice) but the complexity of the assignments made me opt for a GCC compiler instead (those const size arrays just made the tasks even harder). Thank yoi for the advice!

Comment: Thanks for saying thank you. It makes it more enjoyable trying to help people.